# Synchronize events in rx in simulations

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have the following streams

```
T1---T2---T3---T4---T5---T6---T7---T8
Q1-Q3-Q7-Q10
```

I would like to combine them so it looks like this

```
Q1--------Q3------------------Q7-----
```

i,e, only release the event Qi when Ti is released.

Is there a simple way to achieve this using RX primitive?

Comment: Take a look at `.combineLatest` operator.

Comment: I had a look a the .combineLatest but it will not pause the `Q` stream. For example, `Q3` will be emitted at `T2`, when it should wait for `T3`.

Comment: The idea is that you will `filter` out unwanted pairs and `map` back to proper  Q-values.

Comment: [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/otSHiPe74SoAQ1b6yabA?p=preview) is the idea implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your relationship is oneway only (that is `T` event occurs before matching `Q` one), you can achieve this with (js syntax to be confirmed):

```
tElts.selectMany(i -> qElts.takeWhile(n -> n<=i).where(n -> n==i))
```

The inner stream will return a single element stream Q3 for T3, and an empty stream for T2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for a JavaScript solution or something in the `System.Reactive` namespace.  I have this .NET solution that works.  This solution assumes that the Q's will always be generated faster than the T's, i.e. Q<sub>n</sub> will never be generated after T<sub>n</sub> for all n.

```
// Generate 8 T's, 1 per second.
IObservable<int> tSource = 
    Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Select(x => (int)(x + 1))
    .Take(8);

// Generate 4 Q's immediately.
IObservable<int> qSource =
    (new int[] { 1, 3, 7, 10 })
    .ToObservable();

var result = 
    qSource
    .SelectMany(x => 
        tSource
        .Where(y => x == y)
        .Take(1));
```

Interesting note, this looks like the dual of Gluck's solution which also works.

Answer (score 0):

The [zip](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) operator synchronizes multiple streams.

Comment: I think zipping will not work, as T3 will be paired with Q7.